# phpinfo() displays Wrong version openssl in OS X

Tags: macos, php, openssl

I upgraded openssl from version 0.9.8zc to OpenSSL 1.0.2 version. I used this web page [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x) to do this. The next step I upgraded php to 5.6 version from this web page http://php-osx.liip.ch . When I checked openssl version in terminal it was correct version 1.0.2 but  phpinfo() always shows old 0.9.8zc openssl version . What is wrong? Is in my mac installed new version but apache uses old version? How can I change it?

Comment: Paste the output of `/usr/bin/openssl version -a`

Comment: Terminal output is OpenSSL 1.0.2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl" but phpinfo() displays 

Apache Version Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.6.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8zc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the version of PHP that came with your Mac is compiled with the version of OpenSSL that came with it, too. By you compiling OpenSSL, all you did was compile a separate version.

If you compiled PHP and told it to use the newer version, that would work.