# how to make Mac use latest openssl instead of /System/Library/OpenSSL

Tags: macos, openssl

I just (in June 2016) ran the following instructions to update Openssl (in /usr/local/openssl) on my Mac, but when I check the version, it's showing that I'm using a version built in 2015 (the System/Library/OpenSSL version).

Question: what can I do to get my Mac (running El Capitain) to use the latest version I installed?

**The commands I ran to use the latest version:**

```
cd /usr/local/src
curl --remote-name https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz
Extract the archive and move into the folder.

tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2h.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2h
Compile and Install
Configure, compile and install into /usr/local/openssl-1.0.2h.

./configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2h
make depend
make
make install
Create a symbolic link that points /usr/local/openssl to /usr/local/openssl-1.0.2h.

ln -s openssl-1.0.2h /usr/local/openssl
```

When I run `openssl version` in the terminal, it shows me this output (the important part is that it was built in July 2015 and is the System/Library/Openssl)

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
built on: Jul 31 2015
platform: darwin64-x86_64-llvm
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O3 -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_NO_IDEA -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
OPENSSLDIR: "/System/Library/OpenSSL"
```

Comment: `/usr/local` is not in your PATH variable but `/usr/local/bin` should be. Try- `ln -s openssl-1.0.2h /usr/local/bin/openssl`

Comment: are you referring to this? `ln -s openssl-1.0.2h /usr/local/openssl` , so I should try `ln -s openssl-1.0.2h /usr/local/bin/openssl`?

Comment: I ran that. when I cd into `/usr/local/bin` and run `openssl` it gives me the old version `OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015` ....even if the version in path was the old version, if I link the new version to /usr/local/bin, would you expect it to run the new or old version if I run `openssl` from /usr/local/bin?

Comment: same result after running `hash -r` and opening new terminal window (and yes I'm using bash)

Answer (score 1):

Determine where the binary file `openssl` is located.

```
find /usr/local -name 'openssl*' -exec ls -lFd {} +
```

The binary file should have `/bin/openssl*` at the end of the absolute path. Also open a Finder window to view the file system in the GUI with the command

```
open /usr/local
```

Remove any symbolic links that you have created so far then make a new symbolic link to /usr/local/bin/openssl.

[This thread also has helpful details on openssl](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x) options and managing your path to select an alternate version.